# Android Custom Action Bar LinearLayout with equally spaced buttons

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-linearlayout, android-actionbar-compat

**FIXED**

I fixed this problem by simply removing the action bar and using the support library's toolbar instead. I have added the toolbar into my activity's XML file. Moreover, I have removed the default paddings of my root view (RelativeLayout) which have been chreated by Android Studio on creating the activity and which have initially not been notified by me. Furhtermore, I have used "match_parent" instead of "0dp" as image button width.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".BluetoothConnectionManager">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/tbMenu"
    xmlns:application="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/hafnertec"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/miBluetoothConnection"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_bluetooth_searching"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_menu_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:onClick="showDialogueCloseBluetoothConnection"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/miHome"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_bluetooth_searching"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_menu_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:onClick="switchToHomeFragment"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/miGraphsBurnOffCurves"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_bluetooth_searching"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_menu_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:onClick="switchToBurnOffGraphsFragment"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/miConfigurationMode"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_bluetooth_searching"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_menu_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/miExpertMode"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_bluetooth_searching"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_menu_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm writing an Android application which makes use of a custom action bar. I want this action bar to display five button which are equally spaced. For accomplishing this task I use the following XML file (As the icons are still in work all buttons share the same icon.):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageButton android:id="@+id/miBluetoothConnection"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_bluetooth_searching"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_menu_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:onClick="showDialogueCloseBluetoothConnection"/>

<ImageButton android:id="@+id/miHome"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_bluetooth_searching"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_menu_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:onClick="switchToHomeFragment"/>

<ImageButton android:id="@+id/miGraphsBurnOffCurves"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_bluetooth_searching"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_menu_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

<ImageButton android:id="@+id/miConfigurationMode"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_bluetooth_searching"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_menu_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

<ImageButton android:id="@+id/miExpertMode"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_bluetooth_searching"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_menu_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Working great in the designer this does not work when testing it on a real device. On testing all buttons are squeezed together and there is absolutely no spacing between them. The preview in the designer and a screenshot made with my testing device can be seen below.

[Action bar displayed by the designer](https://copy.com/R32VX2Tj2PJ4C89b)

[Action bar on my testing device](https://copy.com/iMH9fDaJKgwUhIBC)

I have also tried wrapping my LinearLayout into a RelativeLayout as well as using a TableLayout. However, non of these things work. Using a RelativeLayout the fifth button is not as big as the other ones.

For adding the action bar to my application I use the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...
    // add the custom action bar
    this.abMainMenu = this.getSupportActionBar();
    this.abMainMenu.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    LayoutInflater liAddActionBar = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    this.customActionBar = liAddActionBar.inflate(ApplicationSettings.LAYOUT_REFERENCE_MAIN_MENU, null);
    this.abMainMenu.setCustomView(this.customActionBar);
    ...
}
```

I am testing on a Samsung Galaxy S I9000 with CyanogenMod 11 December screenshot (Android 4.4.4).

I appreciate any help!

Thanks,

Lukas

Comment: I have tried to implement this solution in my layout but I get the next issue: "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 'android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar' on path: /data/app/com.adapta-2.apk at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)" ... how I can solve this situation? Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that you have forgotten to include the Android support library. I hope [Google's tutorial](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) can give you further instructions including the library. If not please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the toolbar?

Comment: I followed this guide: https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/ However, I still had the same layout problems.

Comment: You don't need to call the seSupportActionBar method in your case. Just treat the toolbar as any other layout. Ins styles.xml select a theme with no action bar.

Comment: Also you did not set the weightSum attribute in the root layout. And the width of each button should be match parent in order for weights to work.

Comment: I've successfully added the action bar containing my menu. Moreover, I have removed the default margin created by Android Studio and not noticed by me. Now it works perfect. For balancing the bigger padding on the left side of the toolbar I simply added some (12dp) on the right side. Thanks, Material Design ;) And thanks for the answer!